# Certificate error DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID

Tags: ssl, iis, server, certificate, local

I have a local server IIS installation I want to secure with ssl. The ful qualified url is testdb.local.domain bit I just access the website with "testdb/"

When I configured the ssl certificate I set CN=testdb.local.domain and DNS = testdb.local.domain. When I now browse the side Internet Explorer throws a not secure error DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID

What CN and DNS do I have to configure so the ssl certificate is working with just using "testdb/"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from the comment.

To make an HTTPS site accessible from different domain names (including machine name), you need corresponding bindings and certificates.

The simplest is to use a SAN certificate, which contains multiple DNS names, and each matches a domain name your site is serving.

You can also use SNI to set up multiple certificates.